# Is there a way in where I can filter by No Fill after conditional formatting in Excel, using Python?

Tags: python, excel, filtering, conditional-formatting

So I have two columns in Excel (Column A and B) and I was able to write the code to get it to highlight the duplicates with conditional formatting using python. I now want to be able to filter Column A by No fill based on the conditional formatting. Is there a way with python where I would be able to do this or some way to accomplish the same thing?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing it's doable with xlwings or win32com.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.